# How to create an array from 1 to N in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, converters

What I want to do is creating an array from 1 to N and call it `first_array`, then combining it with another array(`second array`) with the same length and make a new array object like below:

```
new_array = [
  {
    "name": "first_array[0]",
    "value": second_array[0]
  },
  {
    "name": "first_array[1]",
    "value": second_array[2]
  },
    "name": "first_array[2]",
    "value": second_array[2]

];
```

Comment: So, what do you have so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: just use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want an array from 1 to `N`, you can create a new array of length `N`, fill it with a filler value, then populate the values using their indices with `.map`.

For example:

```js
const n = 10;
const myArray = new Array(n).fill(null).map((_, i) => i + 1);
```

with result for `myArray`:

```js
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

However in this case, it seems you don't need that array if you're just using it alongside another array. Instead you can use the index from that other array (`second_array`) as values for the `"name"` key.

Like this:

```js
const newArray = secondArray.map((e, i) => ({
    name: i + 1,
    value: e,
}));
```

Example case:

*Input*

```js
const secondArray = [100, 200, 300];
```

*Result (for `newArray`)*

```js
[
  { name: 1, value: 100 },
  { name: 2, value: 200 },
  { name: 3, value: 300 }
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I can't understand what is the `e` in your code?

Comment: `e` (first argument of `map`) is an element of `secondArray`. The way `map` works is by applying the given function to each element in the current array and returning an new array composed of the results from calling that function. So, in the example at the bottom `e` is `100` on the first call, `200` on the second, and `300` on the third.

Comment: Just one question. If I want to have name keys in form of string instead of integers, how should I edit your code? I am trying to plot my array using `ngx-charts-line` library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791587/how-to-show-one-dimensional-array-inside-ngx-charts-line

Comment: You can call `.toString()` on each value to cast to a string. For example `{name: (i + 1).toString(), value: e.toString()}`

Comment: May you chek my other question I put it's link? Mybe there is a better way to solve my main problem there?

Answer (score 1):

First create an array with the maximum number of expected elements. Then reduce this array of empty elements to the merged array:

```js
let array_1th = [1,2,3,4]
let array_2nd = [5,6,7,8];

let merged = Array(Math.max(array_1th.length, array_2nd.length))
   .fill().map((_, i) => ({ name: array_1th[i], value: array_2nd[i] }));
   
console.log(merged);
```

A small downside of the above example is that two arrays would be created, with the prepared empty array being discarded afterwards.

A slightly nicer solution is to use `reduce` to mutate the input array directly so that only one array is created:

```js
let array_1th = [1,2,3,4]
let array_2nd = [5,6,7,8];

let merged = Array(Math.max(array_1th.length, array_2nd.length)).fill()
   .reduce((_, __, i, array) => (array[i] = { name: array_1th[i], value: array_2nd[i] }, array), null);
   
console.log(merged);
```